# SessionHandler::write(): Parent session handler is not open

Tags: php, session, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosfacebookbundle

I'm using FOSFacebookBundle in Symfony 2.3 as it says in [the Integration with FOSUserBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-integration-with-fosuserbundle.md). And edited `security.yml`, ran the code but I got the error:

```
Warning: SessionHandler::write(): Parent session handler is not open in /var/www/my/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 407
```

so I gave the permissions:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R app/cache
sudo chmod 777 -R app/logs
```

When I login again, and then logout page I get the same error.

I see this https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5868 and update the php.

But this problem is not solve I don't know why ?
Any one know please tell me ?

`security.yml`

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    chain_provider:
      chain:
        providers: [fos_userbundle, my_fos_facebook_provider]
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    my_fos_facebook_provider:
        id: my.facebook.user    

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        fos_facebook:
            app_url: "http://apps.facebook.com/xxxx/"
            server_url: "http://symfony/app_dev.php/login"
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /loginFb
            default_target_path: /
            provider: my_fos_facebook_provider
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check     
            provider: fos_userbundle
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/secured/.*, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY] }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I think this is not because FOSBundle, i tried logout too with my own lib, and get same error. i using php5.4.10. Follow @Tristan suggest to update your PHP version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem like mentionned in the ticket on github is a bug related to `PHP` so there is noting to do in the Symfony2 side.

Consider moving away from your current `php 5.4.x` to a newer version.

According to this comming **you should be at least using >= php 5.4.11**

See [this commit](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioDistributionBundle/commit/2a518e7c957b66c9478730ca95f67e16ccdc982b)

Answer (score 1):

Fast solution could be:

```
logout:
    invalidate_session: false
```

**EDIT:**

**Be aware session will not be destroyed after logout**.
I would recommend @Tristan solution.